# maven run test when surefire skipTest enabled by default

Tags: java, maven

I try to run unit tests when surefire by default skipped tests in pom.xml.
this is my pom.xml surefire configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M5</junit.jupiter.version>
        <junit.vintage.version>4.12.0-M5</junit.vintage.version>
        <junit.platform.version>1.0.0-M5</junit.platform.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.platform.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.vintage.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                ir.moke.jenkins.MyLib
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and i run this command :

```
mvn clean compile test -DskipTests=false
```

this is console log:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jenkins-tutorial ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/mah454/Programming/java/jenkins-tutorial/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ jenkins-tutorial ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
```

according to this document:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html
I want to run test in this case .
How can fix this problem ?

Here's my project: https://github.com/mah454/jenkins-tutorial

Comment: The linked page to the Maven Surefire Plugin tells you exactly how to do that. So ... what is your question?

Comment: I have not any problem with vote down , but please do not this without any explanation .

Comment: test skipped , I want to run tests ...

Comment: What does it say in the console now when run the command? Also try to removing the `include` tag

Comment: @Davide why i remove include ? this is include not exclude ! ,any way i test your solution . not working .  I think this is a bug .

Comment: I would be surprised if this were a bug. Maybe it could be that something is wrong with the filter and it's not finding any test. Plus, that `includes` uses the default suffix, so it's not really necessary.

Comment: If you have the project on github, or similar, I can have a look

Comment: @Davide github link: https://github.com/mah454/jenkins-tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `SampleTestClass` in your project to `SampleTest` and then you can run the command:

```
mvn test -DskipTests=false
```

The default name for a test class must end with `Test`.

Or you can change the `includes` configuration to:

```
<includes>
    <include>*TestClass</include>
</includes>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens often, more and more, because the people do not read the documentations, example: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Pls use the postfix **Test** and not **TestClass** in the file name. You can freely use the postfix **TestCase** but it is already obsolete. If you rely on the defaults, you would **NOT** use the sections

```
<includes>
    <include>xxx</include>
</includes>
```

The plugins in CI rely on the default postfixes, no need to reconfigure them!